# Possible to include Client JAVA API libraries in Web-services?

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, rtc

We want to develop a Java based Web-services  (since the API's we want to use are Java based)

I would like to know if it's possible to use the IBM Rational Team Concert Plain Java API's (https://jazz.net/downloads/rational-team-concert/releases/5.0/RTC-Client-plainJavaLib-5.0.zip) as part of the Web-servicesand deploy them in the server?

Basically we use these API's on a client based Java applications. What I am looking at is more like a services which can be consumed by many applications

Anyone has any experience in deploying the client based API in the server as Web-services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After multiple tries, it is possible to use the RTC Plain Java API's as Webservices.

How I did:

- Followed the simple Webs Service creation tutorial (http://wiki.eclipse.org/Creating_a_Bottom-Up_Java_Web_Service)
- Adapted to my needs
- First added the "RTC plain Java API's (JAR's)"  to the Eclipse build path
- Then added the "RTC plain Java API's (JAR's)" to the "WebContent/Lib/" folder of my Dynamic web project
- Created a new Web service & Web service client

I was able to login to RTC via this for starters

Comment: my bad, Sorry. I have updated the answer on how I did.